# Reading pdf from assets folder using PDFViewer.jar

Tags: android, pdf, assets

I want to read pdf file stored in asset folder using `PDFViewer.jar`,

I tried this way but I am getting error message and it gets unfortunately stopped.

Could anyone help me how to implement it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CopyReadAssets();

}

private void CopyReadAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "ABC.pdf");
    try {
        in = assetManager.open("ABC.pdf");
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/ABC.pdf"),
            "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}


}
```

logcat details:

```
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
   ComponentInfo{com.syntel.pdfreader/com.syntel.pdfreader.MainActivity}: 
   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:   No Activity found to handle Intent {
    act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/com.syntel.pdfreader/files/ABC.pdf typ=application/pdf    }
  02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):   at    

  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
  02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):   at  
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
  02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):   at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):    at 
  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
  02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):     at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):     at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):    at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activit
y found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
  dat=file:///data/data/com.syntel.pdfreader/files/ABC.pdf typ=application/pdf }
02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):     at  
 android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
02-05 11:09:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(6516):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
```

Comment: @PratikButani Path means its jar file so I have kept it in library folder

Comment: @PratikButani from www.ziddu.com/download/19248664/PdfViewer.jar.html

Comment: Will you please post your logcat errors?

Comment: @PratikButaniI am having the same code but I dont know why it is throwing Activity not found exception

Comment: @PratikButaniok can you give your email id

Comment: @PratikButaniI am not able to send project this is the code I have used  it is unfortunately getting stopped for Intent code.Could you help me out.

Comment: I have sent you code. Check and reply me

Comment: Emulator doesn't have any built in pdf reader that why you are getting this error, Its working on device perfectly.

Comment: @PratikButani yes I got now But I dont want that Iwant it to open using PDFViewer.jar

Comment: @PratikButanithanks Sure will do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created my live demo using this [Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

You can download my [Demo with Library](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zl1adgsd5adyl3k/OpenAssetsPDF.zip)