# getting blank pdf on implementing pdf reader in project

Tags: java, android, pdf

i am trying to implement a pdf reader via a pdf library from git hub https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library but when i implement the code.. all i am getting is a blank page.. the url is correct the pdf has content and this is similar to this q .. [Example of code to implement a PDF reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader)

my code consist of multiple methods, the main method is used to select the which pdf should be chosen to display. then the pdf name is passed on to method "copyreadassets"

```
public void CopyReadAssets(String url) {
      AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
      InputStream in = null;
      OutputStream out = null;
      File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), url);
      try {
               in = assetManager.open(url);
               out = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(file.getName(),
               Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

               copyFile(in, out);
               in.close();
               in = null;
               out.flush();
               out.close();
               out = null;
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
      }
      String path = "file://" + getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/"+url;
      openPdfIntent(path);  }
```

the openpdfintentmethod is used to open the values

```
  private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Question_Point_Main.this, Pdf.class);
            intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

pdf.class contains the following..

```
public class Pdf extends Activity{

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;  }
public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;  }
public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;  }
public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;  }
public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    return R.id.etPassword;  }
public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    return R.id.btOK;  }
public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    return R.id.btExit; }
public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
```

}

Comment: [You can try this example it worked for me ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575792/reading-pdf-from-assets-folder-using-pdfviewer-jar

Comment: Sorry chat is blocked for my system

Comment: check in on device because it may happen becasue of less memory

Comment: @poojagupta  yes on device its showing an xml that has all images i have in the drawing folder, which I have not created...

Answer (score 0):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


 <activity android:name="com.example.readassetpdf.myPDFActivity"></activity>
```

in your case activity is **pdf class**

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.readassetpdf.pdf"></activity>
```

and use following method

```
public void CopyReadAssets(String url) {
      AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
      InputStream in = null;
      OutputStream out = null;
      File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), url);
      try {
               in = assetManager.open(url);
               //out = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(file.getName(),
               //Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
               out=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/mypdf.pdf");
               copyFile(in, out);
               in.close();
               in = null;
               out.flush();
               out.close();
               out = null;
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
      }
      String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/mypdf.pdf";
      openPdfIntent(path);  
      }
```

and call it as below

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CopyReadAssets("mypdf.pdf");
}
```

And the function copyfile is as below

```
   private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out)  throws IOException{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

The replacement is

```
out = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(file.getName(),
Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

to

```
out=new   FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/mypdf.pdf");
```

Comment: hi i did as u asked but its showing loading pdf page and continuing to load with no change.. (on emulator) on my device its loading for some time then a page which is basically a combination of all my xml 's is shown..